# How to find source of the problem for code: 153 in IOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have a react-native app and I use Expo V49 to handle dependencies and release.

When I run my app over expo Go, it works perfectly, no problem at all. But when I make a TestFlight release over expo, the app crashes immediately, it does not open at all, just a splash is being visible for half of a second.

I tried to find something. The only thing I came across over MacOS's Console is this:

```
error   18:24:03.164308+0200    SpringBoard Scene FBSceneManager/sceneID:app.letscape.www-default update failed: <NSError: 0x28505c120; domain: FBSceneErrorDomain; code: 1 (operation-failed); reason: "Scene update failed."> {
    NSUnderlyingError = <NSError: 0x280e9c7b0; domain: BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain; code: 3 (OperationFailed); reason: "XPC error received on message reply handler">;
}
error   18:24:03.164525+0200    SpringBoard Scene FBSceneManager/sceneID:app.letscape.www-default update failed: <NSError: 0x281195740; domain: FBSceneErrorDomain; code: 1 (operation-failed); reason: "Scene update failed."> {
    NSUnderlyingError = <NSError: 0x280e9c6f0; domain: BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain; code: 3 (OperationFailed); reason: "XPC error received on message reply handler">;
}
error   18:24:03.164994+0200    SpringBoard Scene FBSceneManager/sceneID:app.letscape.www-default update failed: <NSError: 0x28505c8d0; domain: FBSceneErrorDomain; code: 1 (operation-failed); reason: "Scene update failed."> {
    NSUnderlyingError = <NSError: 0x280e9d440; domain: BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain; code: 3 (OperationFailed); reason: "XPC error received on message reply handler">;
}
```

Any ideas how I can approach to pinpoint the place of the problem exactly?

The crash report does not include logs somehow. I am kinda stucked.

My package.json includes these dependencies:

```
"@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/rudder-sdk-node": "^1.1.1",
    "@expo/spawn-async": "^1.7.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@expo/xcpretty": "^4.2.2",
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.3.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "expo": "^49.0.6",
    "expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
    "expo-blur": "~12.4.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.11",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-dropdown-select-list": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-maps": "1.7.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^4.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1"
```

Best

Ali

Comment: Did you make a release for android? If yes, is it working on android or you're facing the same error on android release too?

Comment: Check if this helps you out: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/23606

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using the lib: react-native-reanimated and this was the main reason that the app failed. I installed this lib to try out things but forgot to delete. Seems this lib needs further configs on babel etc. Since I did not do that, it failed I guess.

I deleted it and the app worked.